# Could not complete Oauth2 login

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, google-oauth

Im trying to get the access token from **OAuth 2.0 Playground** through **POSTMAN**. Theses are the configurations. When the Request the token it says **`Could not complete Oauth2 login`**. Any reason why i cannot get the token?. How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: it seems in google `oauth` playground, the oauth flow works great. However, I dont know where to get the `clientId`, `client secret`. where did you get those two?

Comment: @chenrui i got the clientId and ClientSecret from the app i have created in Google API Console. Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: have you set up the postman callback url as a redirect uri in your google console?

Comment: I creatde a dedicated chat room for this, and will post there what I have got so far.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147553/google-oauth2-postman-setup

Answer (score 3):

I also encounter the same problem yesterday. After debugging the request I figure out that postman sends the request to this domain: https://app.getpostman.com
, which is blocked in our internal network. When it is unblocked authorization request working successfully.

Comment: How to unblock that website internally in our pc?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Joshi's answer, the missing part that the Google API needs to know how 
 to call back to Postman.

In the first screen is where Postman shows you the callback URL to use, which as of March 2018 is https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback   I imagine this can change.

[image]

In the second screen is in the Google API settings where you set that callback URL.  Your "Client ID for Web Application" needs to call back to Postman to complete the authorization.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case (ubuntu) I had to turn off SSL verification

> File > Settings > General Tab > REQUEST Section > SSL certificate verification = OFF:

[image]

Source: https://community.postman.com/t/could-not-complete-oauth-2-0-login-check-postman-console-for-more-details/6350